# How to use Lagrangian multipliers with inequality constraints?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Can anyone assist me with guidance on how to solve the following max and min with constraints problem where the side conditions are inequalities, using Lagrangian multipliers?
I was able to successfully solve the problem using other methods but, I have not had success in solving the problem using Lagrangian multipliers.

For any help you could provide, I will be greatly grateful beforehand.
[image]

Comment: First you look for stationary points inside the triangle, i.e. the points where $\nabla f(x,y)$ vanishes. Then you inspect the sides of the triangle. For two sides of the triangle the problem reduces to one variable.  For the third one, $y=3x,$  you may use the Lagrange multipliers method. You collect all the points, which were obtained, and evaluate $f$ at them.

Comment: The KKT conditions are how to use Lagrange multipliers with (combination of equality and) inequality constraints. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions